# Absolute Zero and Existence

Tags: philosophy-of-science

If the universe were at absolute zero, space-time exist?  That is, does space-time require heat to exist?

Comment: i'm looking forward to any answers!!

Comment: According to Leibnizian space-time [relationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationalism) advocated by Mach and impressed by Einstein, they may never exist physically and ontologically even with non-absolute zero temperature. They're merely systems of relations that exist between objects, not unlike the system of relations between a father and his multiple children...

Comment: Sounds like a physics question. Not sure why it's on the philosophy site.

Answer (score 1):

Spacetime without matter in it does not require the concept of temperature to exist.

*Classical* spacetime with matter in it does not require temperature either.

*Quantum* spacetime with matter in it imposes limits on how close you can get to absolute zero.

Comment: Nicely put. No further explanation needed, methinks.